with Renovate.json in yaml file it should update SNAPSHOT version
I am trying to update snapshot version in yaml file with renovate
but its not creating PR (this thing is working for release but not for snapshot)
{
    "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
    "extends": ["config:base"],
    "regexManagers": [
  
      {
        "fileMatch": [
            "configuration/release_x86_64\\.yaml$"
        ],
        "groupName": "all dependencies",
        "matchStrings": [
            "version: (?<currentValue>.*) #abc"
        ],
        "depNameTemplate": "FCA",
        "datasourceTemplate": "artifactory",
        "registryUrlTemplate": "https://abc/built",
        "ignoreUnstable": false
      }
    ],
    "packageRules": [
        {
            "groupName": "all dependencies",
            "groupSlug": "all",
            "matchDatasources": ["artifactory"],
            "enabled": true,
            "versioning": "loose",
            "prerelease":true,
            "artifactory":{
              "includeSnapshots": true
            },
            "ignoreUnstable": false
        }
    ]       
  }

added all of these "versioning", prerelease, includeSnapshots, ignoreUnstable
but it is not able to update Snapshot
release_x86_64.yaml looks like this
---
release_units:
  - set: fca
    version: 3.14.0 #abc
    components: ["FCA"]


it should create PR in
release_x86_64.yaml
---
release_units:
  - set: fca
    version: FCA_PR3_SNAPSHOT #abc
    components: ["FCA"]

